# Are “Quantum fluctuations” composed of constructive and destructive interference waves, creation and annihilation waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, vacuum, virtual-particles

The question is: In a “Quantum vacuum state” are particles being created from constructive wave interference. Are particles being created from series of constructive waves, superposition (Fourier transform) and then being annihilated likewise?

Thank you

Comment: The person who popularized "quantum fluctuations" did a great disservice to the world. Absolutely nothing in quantum mechanics "fluctuates". This is ruled out by the fluctuation-dissipation theorem and more complex analyses of systems that can be described by random forces. Superposition is a property of the quantum mechanical ensemble. A single quantum mechanical system is simply "uncertain", i.e. we can not assign a unique classical state to it while unmeasured. So, no, I would not suggest that you try to think about a quantum mechanical system as being "somehow constructed of waves".

Comment: @FlatterMann But thinking of states as being constructed of waves is useful; this is just the fourier transform isn't it?

Comment: A Fourier transform on the wave function of the ensemble is merely a linear operation. All by itself it doesn't contain any physics. You can define an infinity of perfectly equivalent linear transformations and their inverses. Nature doesn't care. The problem with "quantum mechanical fluctuations" is not the math but that somebody decided that a specific (but otherwise unremarkable and hardly unique) mathematical operation that leaves no trace in nature had to represent physical reality. It doesn't.

Comment: On a side note, I don't believe that most physicists associate the "fluctuations" with Fourier analysis of states. They are more likely to think about perturbation theory in quantum field theory. That's not quite the same thing, but my remarks apply as well. Perturbation theory doesn't lead to "fluctuations", it allows us to more easily calculate shifts in energy levels and line widths.

Comment: Yes, I will research: Perturbation theory doesn't lead to "fluctuations". Thank you